# HP printer has many problems

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I'm experiencing a number of issues with my new HP M477DFW laserjet printer:

1. It will periodically disconnect from my wireless network.
2. When this happens, I will open the wireless setup wizard, and it will tell me there are no wireless networks in range. I have to turn the printer off and then back on again, and then it detects the dozen or so wireless networks in range.
3. It will periodically not print from some devices. Right now, it will print from my desktop and my phone (Nexus 5x), but it won't print from my Macbook (which I have printed from before).
4. It will sometimes not be discoverable for devices. My wife's laptop cannot find it, and when I removed it from my Macbook to re-add it, it can no longer find it. Previously I had this issue on my desktop, and support had me manually add it by IP. After that, it was discoverable from devices for a time, but no longer.
5. Not the printer itself, but when I run the HP Print and Scan Doctor, every time it starts up it says that an update is available. I've let it download and (supposedly) install these updates many times, including 5 times back to back, but it still insists there is another update available. The Print and Scan Doctor also completely fails to detect any of these issues.

Are HP printers as terrible as this one makes them seem? Or have I just gotten really unlucky with this one?

Any help would be appreciated, as I really don't want to lug this 100 pound beast back to Microcenter.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) `Are HP printers as terrible as this one makes them seem?`. My experience is yes, they are. 500+MB driver packs, irreliable operation. I'll never buy a HP printer again.  2) as to trying to solve your problem: What is the wireless signal strength? (Use something like SSIDinsider). 2b) Did you assign it a MAC/IP reservation? (an other common problem is printers changing ID, though that should not result in wireless singnal loss.

Comment: Can you recommend an alternate brand?

Wireless signal strength is excellent (the device even says so). It's sitting on the same desk as the router, with only 4 feet of open feet between the two.

I just gave it a static IP. Could that resolve the issues devices have in discovering it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a wired connection? For printers I have always found that to be far more reliable than WiFi.

Comment: What is your actual question?  If you're asking people's opinion about HP or printer recommendations, those are off-topic.  If you want help diagnosing your problem, there isn't enough information.

Comment: I think you got a lemon, take it back or ring HP. I've had the same printer for 6 months without any hitch at all.

Comment: I've had trouble with many printer brands and wireless and so do not use it. Even in otherwise normal operation sleeping makes printing annoying: the radio turns off when the device is asleep and there's no way to wake it to print. Wired is just a better way to go in general with printers.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a consulting business with approximately 80 users and about 15 printers of various makes but the most common is HP. My observations as the main technical person of the printers are as follows:

- Not all SMEs can afford to put a professional grade printer in every corner of the office, sometimes this is due to cost and at others times because it is physically impractical. For this reason, we have a mixture of HP Laserjet and Officejet machines.
- Single users who use Deskjet or Officejet printers generally don't complain about failure. Cartridge costs are understandably higher when it is time to replace but usage is generally low, and the convenience makes it worth it
- Officejet(s) and Deskjet(s) used by multiple users have the highest failure rates. Typical failures involve mechanical breakdown of the paper loader and sensor. We've usually gone about 18 months until a replacement is required.
- Other problems include:

  - Drivers which work on Windows but not on Mac
  - Drivers which require installation of additional software such as photo printing service
  - Wireless connections dropping out suddenly
  - Slow startup/resume
  - Too costly to repair seemingly simple faults
- We have the best experience with Lasejet machines. Most are more than 4 years old and still in excellent condition. There has never been a mechanical failure, but complex electronic failure has required outright replacement.
- Typical benefits:

  - Warm up is fast
  - Memory can store entire job allowing remote users to disconnect from network
  - Duplex printing
  - Other functions such as envelope printing work as advertised